# How to determine which field is lookup field via REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, list-view, lookup-column

I have to load data from various lists with various views via SharePoint 2013 REST API. I have no knowledge about fields that are configured in views (general fields, custom fields, lookup fields, etc.).

I am able to determine which fields are on specific view:

REQUEST

```
http://<myurl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyList')/Views$select=Id,Title,ViewFields&$expand=ViewFields
```

RESPONSE

```
{  "Id" : "89d0891d-b4a9-1111-1111-0881d8a35c0d",
    "Title" : "My First View",
    "ViewFields" : {
       "SchemaXml" : ..."Items" : {
       "results" : [ "Field1", "Field2", "w9ft", "q37c", "Field5" ]
  },
{  "Id" : "89d0891d-b4a9-2222-2222-0881d8a35c0d",
   "Title" : "My Second View",
   "ViewFields" : {
       "SchemaXml" : ..."Items" : {
       "results" : [ "Field6", "Field7", "ab4tg", "Field9" ]
  }
```

Problem is when I try to get the data from views, e.g. from "My First View":

REQUEST

```
http://<myurl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyList')/Items$select=Field1,Field2,w9ft,q37c,Field5
```

RESPONSE

```
{ "error": { ...
   "message": The query to field 'w9ft' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains w9ft.
```

Which means that field `w9ft` is lookup field. In general, the same error can occur for any other field I have to load (`Field1`, `Field2`, etc.).

Therefore I need some mechanism how to determine which field is lookup field and add suffix `Id` to these field names (e.g. `http://<myurl>/_api...$select=Field1Id,Field2,w9ftId,...` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query should return Look up fields

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Your List Name')/Fields?$filter=TypeShortDescription eq 'Lookup (information already on this site)'
```

**Conditions** it will not work if you put ant custom description!

**Update** following will work in all scenario, I hope

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Your List Name')/Fields?$filter=TypeAsString eq 'Lookup' and ReadOnlyField eq false and Hidden eq false
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine which fields are lookups you could take each field that is returned, e.g. `"Field1", "Field2", "w9ft", "q37c", "Field5"` and for each of these fields make REST calls to ascertain their type, like so:

```
http://<myurl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyList')/Fields?$select=TypeAsString&$filter=Title eq 'w9ft'
```

Or you can filter on the field's internal name with `$filter=InternalName eq 'w9ft'`